# Get the key based on the value item

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is as follows:

```
{
    'city1': {
        u 'region1': [u 'street1']
    },
    'city2': {
        u 'region2': [u 'street2', u 'street3']
    }
}
```

I need to get the key "region1" if "street1" is present in the list, that is I will pass one item as a input , need to check the list whether it is exists, If exists need to return the key of the same.

I need to achieve this with minimum for loop iterations.

Comment: All we have is a set of requirements. Where did you get stuck when you tried to build this? What piece of code can we help you with?

Comment: Did you see [Get key by value in dictionary](//stackoverflow.com/q/8023306) yet? You'll have to do a full scan, or create a reverse index if you need to do this repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = {'city1': {'region1': [ u'street1']},
     'city2': {'region2': [u'street2', u'street3']}} 

print [sub_key for key in d for sub_key in d[key] if 'street1' in d[key][sub_key]]
```

This will output:

```
['region1']
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Working as expected

Comment: @sathis You're welcome!